# How to iterate hashmap containing Object and array object, in jsp using jstl

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, hashmap, jstl

I am not very good in JSTL.  I would be glad to get some help.

I have below Map object in my java class:

```
Map<Integer, Result[]> qrCodeMap = new HashMap<Integer, Result[]>();
Result qrCodeResult[] = null;

...............(some lines of code)

for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) 

{
..............
qrCodeResult = new QRCodeMultiReader().decodeMultiple(binaryBitmap, hintMap);
qrCodeMap.put(new Integer(i + 1), qrCodeResult);
 }
```

Now my qrCodeMap has Integer and Result[] array object

I add this map object to model in my Spring Controller :

```
model.addAttribute("qrCodeMap", qrCodeMap);
```

I want to display qrCodeMap in jsp using jstl. Could you please tell me how I should iterate through qrCodeMap (ie. a Map) in jsp?  Below is my incomplete code:

```
<c:forEach var="qrCode" items="${qrCodeMap}">
For Page ${qrCode.key} , QR Codes : 
<c:forEach items="${qrCode.value}" var="item">
</c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

If it is easier to do through scriplets, then kindly suggest the syntax.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<c:forEach var="qrCode" items="${qrCodeMap}">
    For Page: ${qrCode.key} , QR Codes :<br/>
    <c:forEach var="result" items="${qrCode.value}">
        ${result.attr}<br/>
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Where `attr` is the attribute you want to show from `Result`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Sedooe. Also, thank you to Stackoverflow for such wonderful website.  Success is never achieved alone.  There is always someone who helps you.  Best Regards.

Comment: @Pallavi please have a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thank you, I did not knew that.